# Is it possible to use Coffee Mill for other grain?

Tags: flour, grains, milling

I'm in Argentina here I cannot fing buckwheat flour so I bought instead buckwheat grain and I want to 
mill it to get flour....

but I don't arrive to find a tradicional Mill (at a cheap price)
I want to know if with a machine like this cofee mill I could get good flour?

[image]

Comment: The problem you're going to have with that is volume. You'll only be able to do a small amount at a time. I'd suggest you search for another option.

Comment: you're right I will continu to look for another solution maybe a DIY mill. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a nice picture of a spinning blade type spice grinder you have there. The good ones will even do whole nutmegs. You can also use it to make limited quantities of powdered sugar, oat flour, wheat flour, buckwheat flour etc. About any non-oily seed may be turned into a powder with that grinder.
Trying to make peanut butter is a mistake. It goos up the blades something awful.

Comment: all sellers advised me that, but as they are seller I had to be sure :-) , I putted this picture to avoid linking to any marketplace.

Comment: so mill almond with that will be a bad Idea, don't you think?

Comment: You can do nuts and the like if you're quick about it. Only pulse a few times and you'll get small pieces. More, and it turns to sticky paste. There may well be nuts that don't work well at all.

Comment: ok thx, I will try it